# The box shadow only works on the title

Tags: html, css

[Here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPm2r.png) So I want to put a box shadow around the text and image so I put both of them in another div and set the style for the box shadow but it didn't work, it only works on the title so how can I fix this? Here is my code:

```html
<div style="box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #d4d4d4;">
        
            <h1 style="padding-bottom:10px">About us</h1>
            <div class="left" style="padding-bottom: 100px;">
                <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. 
Praesent libero. Sed
                    cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi.
                    Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. 
Fusce nec tellus
                    sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa.
                    Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora 
torquent per conubia
                    nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
                
                    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. 
Praesent libero. Sed
                        cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi.
                        Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent 
mauris. Fusce nec tellus
                        sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa.
                        Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora 
torquent per conubia
                        nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
                    
                        <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec 
odio. Praesent libero. Sed
                            cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi.
                            Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent 
mauris. Fusce nec tellus
                            sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa.
                            Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad 
litora torquent per conubia
                            nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>

                
            </div>
            <div class="right" > <img src="images/aboutuspic.jpg " width= "300" height="200" 
style="text-align: right;float:right;  border-radius: 25px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS code for the two divs :

```
.left {
    padding: 20;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    }

    .right {
    padding: 20;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    }
```

Comment: Add CSS Code here

Comment: @LaljiTadhani he has css code there, he uses inline css code look closely

Comment: so why add this Class here `class="left"`

Comment: you didnt put both on the same div tho, remove the closing div tag below the last `p` tag

Comment: you are usign `float` so `parent` tag `clear` or `overflow:hiddin`

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:hidden`

```
<div style="box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #d4d4d4;overflow: hidden;">
```

```css
.left {
    padding: 20;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    }

    .right {
    padding: 20;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    }
```

```html
<div style="box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #d4d4d4;overflow: hidden;">
        
            <h1 style="padding-bottom:10px">About us</h1>
            <div class="left" style="padding-bottom: 100px;">
                <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. 
Praesent libero. Sed
                    cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi.
                    Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. 
Fusce nec tellus
                    sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa.
                    Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora 
torquent per conubia
                    nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
                
                    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. 
Praesent libero. Sed
                        cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi.
                        Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent 
mauris. Fusce nec tellus
                        sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa.
                        Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora 
torquent per conubia
                        nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
                    
                        <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec 
odio. Praesent libero. Sed
                            cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi.
                            Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent 
mauris. Fusce nec tellus
                            sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa.
                            Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad 
litora torquent per conubia
                            nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>

                
            </div>
            <div class="right" > <img src="images/aboutuspic.jpg " width= "300" height="200" 
style="text-align: right;float:right;  border-radius: 25px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```